# Button doesn't do anything when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, button

[image]So I have a HTML file with a button, and an external js file that should have some functionality. But it doesn't work. Here's the code:

HTML full code:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("play");

btn.addEventListener("click", alertMessage);

function alertMessage() {
  alert("Pls tell me youre working...");
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="text-box">
    <h1>BLOG</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="play"> OK </button>
  </div>
  <script src="music-player/scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You overwrite the default `alert` with your own function, and then you have the function call itself over and over...

Comment: from the image you uploaded it seems you are missing a `<html>` in the beginning of the file.

Comment: I added it and it still doesnt work... not sure whats wrong anymore

Comment: check browser `console`, if you dont find any thing there, copy and paste the code in the snippet in the respective files, and run it, if it runs, then add the desired elements afterwards.

Comment: OK so I pasted the js code in the console and then when i clicked the button it worked. Maybe theres an issue with this line <script src="music-player/scripts/app.js"></script>

Comment: also it said this in console Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: there is i guess, the path is incorrect, it should be `scripts/app.js`.

Comment: Check your dev tools network tab. You should see a 404 error. You have the wrong link to your js if I see this correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Because that make `Maximum call stack size` because the `alert` inside the `function` will not refer to the default global `alert` but to the function itself which makes an infinity recursion, you need to change the function name.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("play");

btn.addEventListener("click", alertMessage);

function alertMessage()
{
  alert("Pls tell me youre working...");
}
```

```html
<div class= "buttons">
    <button id="play"> OK </button>
    </div>
    <script src="music-player/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

If you used `window.alert()` and used function expression instead of a function declaration ( which overite the global alert ) it will work fine, but for sure it would better to change the `function` name to prevent conflicts.

```js
const alert = () =>
{
  window.alert("Pls tell me youre working...");
}

const btn = document.getElementById("play");

btn.addEventListener("click", alert);
```

```html
<div class= "buttons">
    <button id="play"> OK </button>
    </div>
    <script src="music-player/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update function name:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("play");

btn.addEventListener("click", alertMessage);

function alertMessage() {
  alert("Pls tell me youre working...");
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="text-box">
    <h1>BLOG</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="play"> OK </button>
  </div>
  <script src="music-player/scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made my code exactly like yours and it still does nothing =(

Comment: check console and check is there any error?

Comment: @CloudlessStudio can you post the updated code in the question, you just need to update the question you asked and we will try  to debug it using `console` most probably

Comment: ok just posted the updated version

Comment: @CloudlessStudio it seems that some of tags were not closed, i edited the question, it seems to be running.

Comment: it doesnt work on my end =(, is it cause im running it by clicking the html file? I wish i could send a screen shot

Comment: @CloudlessStudio you can add image to your question, check [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post).

Answer (score 0):

Because your index.html file inside music-player folder. You should change script source to "./scripts/app.js"

Answer (score -1):

change the name of the function from **alert to something else** or you can add directly add **onClick="function()"** in button tag it self